# Profile cloning and access settings on new profile

Tags: clone, field-level-security, custom-profile

Is there any way to clone profile and allow that profile to have all field level access as previous(parent) profile?

Scenario is, we haven't set some objects/fields as global on OWD, now when we cloned profile, new profile is not getting access to those fields but getting access as parent profile at just object level.

Is there any way to clone profile in such a way that it will also add that profile in access list for all custom fields for all objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do define your custom fields as OWD for a parent profile, the child profile inherits them directly. This is explained in detail [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hmhXAAQ) as well.

However, if you're not doing that and simply cloning a profile, that won't work - the child profile will not get access. This is listed as an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000lAlmAAE) which is under Point Threshold right now.

Comment: Oh, this is not about parent child relationship for object so first option would not be the case but second scenario explains my issue, as I don't ave OWD and  we're trying to clone the profile, so that is under threshold point and we're probably not getting that soon.